# Asm Assembler - CX loop looping forever

Tags: loops, assembly, infinite-loop

I am using emu8086, www.emu8086.com - and have the following code:

```
data segment

five equ 5
VET db 5 dup (1,2,3,4,5)
w2 db 0

ends

stack segment
dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:

mov ax,data
mov ds, ax
mov es,ax



;sum
xor AX,AX
xor BX,BX
xor CX, CX


mov cl,five
mov si,0

sum:
add al,vet[si]
inc SI
dec cx
loop sum

mov w2,al
;end sum



ends

end start
```

the problem is that I when CX reaches 0, the sum loop shuld stop and the result of the sum be save into w2 variable.

for some strang reason this is not happening at the program is looping forever.

what is the isssue with my code? can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 8086 LOOP instruction decrements CX, then loops if CX is non-zero. In your code here:

```
sum:
add al,vet[si]
inc SI
dec cx
loop sum
```

You are decrementing CX first, then executing LOOP which decrements it again. If you start with an odd value (5, for example) CX will be zero when the LOOP executes, which will decrement it past zero, and the loop will continue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are decrementing CX twice - once explicitly and once in the `loop` instruction. So on each loop iteration the value of CX goes from `5 -> 3 -> 1 -> -1 -> ...` and you have an infinite loop.

Change:

```
sum:
    add al,vet[si]
    inc SI
    dec cx           ; decrement CX
    loop sum         ; decrement CX and branch if not zero
```

to:

```
sum:
    add al,vet[si]
    inc SI
    loop sum         ; decrement CX and branch if not zero
```

Comment: Thank you to both! your contribution has been equally valuable. Unofortunately, I can accept only one answer...